# boolean row of specific values in columns in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying how to find if in column exist anothew value as '0'
The MSSQL server 2005 table has 40 columns and 730 rows, and numeric data.

Example of data in table:

```
date|col1 |col2 |col3 | col4| 
1   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  |      
2   | 45  | 0   | 7   |  0  |     
3   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  |     
4   | 75  | 0   | 0   |  0  | 
5   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  |
6   | 7   | 0   | 0   |  0  | 
7   | 0   | 0   | 7   |  0  | 
8   | 0   | 0   | 7   |  0  |
9   | 0   | 0   | 7   |  0  |
```

And a result what I need is a row of boolean,
where `0`indicates that in column are all records with value '0'
and `1` indicates that in column exist at least one times other value than '0'
A result may be stored in temporary table.

I need something this:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |  
|  1   |  0   |  1   |  0   |
```

How can I do it?  Can anybody help?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT  
    CASE   
        WHEN max(col1) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1  
    END as col1,  
    CASE  
        WHEN max(col2) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1  
    END as col2,   
    CASE  
        WHEN max(col3) = 0  
        THEN 0  
        ELSE 1  
    END as col3,     
        CASE  
        WHEN max(col4) = 0  
        THEN 0  
        ELSE 1  
    END as col4        
FROM table
```

It works fine, but it seems be very complicated. Can anybody suggest
something else?

Comment: That's pretty much the simplest way to do it, and would be pretty good on performance. There are other ways, but none would be overly "better". Your query isn't complicated at all though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to list all 40 columns, you could use dynamic SQL for this:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT '

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'CASE WHEN MAX('+ COLUMN_NAME +') = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As '+ COLUMN_NAME +','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'T'

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1) + ' FROM T'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Result:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |  
|  1   |  0   |  1   |  0   |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do what you did, but there are alternatives...

```
ISNULL(MAX(NULLIF(col1, 0)), 0)
```

That one relies on there being no NULL values (or NULLs can be treated as 0.

This one is the shortest robust version I can think of...

```
MAX(CASE Col1 WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```